# Showing loading items in Ionic Loading Controller

Tags: ionic4

Currently, my loading controller is working fine. but I want to show my loading items from API inside the loading controller.

Comment: What docyou mean you want to show thrm in loading? Can you explain better plz.

Comment: @MostafaHarb Yes I want to show items or percentage in loading controller.

Comment: I've posted the answer that you could use its return value as the percentage of download and in the turorial there is also for upload.

Answer (score 0):

```
public downloadProgress: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);


        getStatusMessage(event){
     let status; 
    switch(event.type){ case HttpEventType.Sent: return `Uploading Files`; 
    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress: status = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total); 
     case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress: status = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total); 

this.downloadProgress.next(status); 
    // NOTE: The Content-Length header must be set on the server to calculate this return `Files are ${status}% downloaded`; 
    case HttpEventType.Response: return `Done`; default: return `Something went wrong` }
    }
```

https://www.joshmorony.com/displaying-upload-download-progress-in-an-ionic-application/

This is the referance you could check for full tutorial.Any additional question i'll be here.